# How to pass/save the data from activity A to B and then to B?

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-activity

i've made a app with eclipse, it's about there buttons, the first button counts the click that I have made, the second button send me to activity B and . In activity B include the third button I've made it to buy 100 click. The problem i faced now when I click the button to buy a 100 click the amount on the mainactivity start from 1000 not and don't save the last clicks  that i made before  I bought.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int count = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivityTwo.class);

            startActivityForResult(intent, count);

        }
    });



final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

final TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent in = getIntent();
        int cou = in.getIntExtra("", 1000);
        // Get the extras (if there are any)
        Bundle extras = in.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

                // TODO: Do something with the value of isNew.
            count++;
            int sum = cou+ count;

            textView1.setText("Clicked "+ sum +":times");


            } else{
             count++;
             textView1.setText("Clicked"+ count +":times");
         }
    }
});
```

}

Activity_Two:

```
public class MainActivityTwo extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("", 1000);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}
}
```

Comment: where is your OnActivityForResult method also post that

Comment: @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check if the requestCode is corresponding to your Second Activity.
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        // Check if result is ok
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {}}}

Comment: On button click you are incrementing count but not passing it to next activity and also use some key name like count instead of "" as key name to add value in intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that code

**Updated MainActtivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static int count = 0;
public static int MAIN_ACTIVITY = 1;

TextView textView1;
Button button1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    MainActivityTwo.class);

            startActivityForResult(intent, MAIN_ACTIVITY);

        }
    });

     button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

     textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            count++;
            textView1.setText("total clicks are => "+count);


        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MAIN_ACTIVITY) { // Check if result is ok

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            int clicks = data.getIntExtra("100_CLICKS", 100);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "you bought "+clicks+" clicks : ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            //now you have 100 clicks here from MainActivityTwo

            int total_clicks=clicks+count;


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Total Clicks Are : ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            textView1.setText("total clicks are => "+total_clicks);

        }
    }

  }
}
```

and MainActivityTwo is

```
public class MainActivityTwo extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Intent mIntent = new Intent();
         mIntent.putExtra("100_CLICKS", 100);
         setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
         finish();

      }
    });


  }
}
```

and in your menifest

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivityTwo"></activity>
```

Comment: change your MainActivity with my Updated MainActivity and run it and tell me if that code is working

Comment: Total clicks = 102 ... after i start clicking again the answer be Total clicks = 3

Comment: you mean after total_Clicks=102 and then start clicking againg the count starts from 0 and if you press click button then 1 and then 2 and then 3 and so on

Comment: in onActivityResult below line textView1.setText("total clicks are => "+total_clicks); write    count=total_clicks;

Answer (score 0):

Use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putInt("clicks", "x") // x is the int that count clicks.
}
```

And

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    x = savedInstanceState.getInt("clicks");
    x + y //y is the newly bought clicks if any.

}
```

onSaveInstanceState is called when Acitivty is paused (that is when you will move from activity A to activity B.

onRestoreInstanceState is called when Activity A resumes. That is, when you come back from Activity B to Activity A